# Unable to use position in CSS perfectly in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to make a recursive react tree component for showing file structure that is present as finder on MacOS, something like this.
[image: Desired result]

This is what I have made so far

[image: My solution]

I built my component by following this article - [Link](https://medium.com/@davidtranwd/implement-tree-view-component-with-reactjs-and-styled-components-5eea3b1603cf)

This is the code for showing the names of the file and the react icons

```
const getPaddingLeft = (level, type) => {
  let paddingLeft = level*100;
  return paddingLeft;
}

const getPaddingTop = (level, type) => {
  let paddingLeft = -level*27.5;
  return paddingLeft;
}

const StyledTreeNode = styled.div`
  display: flex;
position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: left;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  padding-left: ${props => getPaddingLeft(props.level, props.type)}px;
  top: ${props => getPaddingTop(props.level, props.type)}px;
  
`;

const NodeIcon = styled.div`
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: ${props => props.marginRight ? props.marginRight : 5}px;
`;

const getNodeLabel = (node) => last(node.path.split('/'));

const TreeNode = (props) => {
  const { node, getChildNodes, level, onToggle, onNodeSelect } = props;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <StyledTreeNode level={level} type={node.type}>
        <NodeIcon onClick={() => onToggle(node)}>
          { node.type === 'folder' && (node.isOpen ? <FaChevronDown /> : <FaChevronRight />) }
        </NodeIcon>
        
        <NodeIcon marginRight={10}>
          { node.type === 'file' && <FaFile /> }
          { node.type === 'folder' && node.isOpen === true && <FaFolderOpen /> }
          { node.type === 'folder' && !node.isOpen && <FaFolder /> }
        </NodeIcon>
        

        <span role="button" onClick={() => onNodeSelect(node)}>
          { getNodeLabel(node) }
        </span>
      </StyledTreeNode>

      { node.isOpen && getChildNodes(node).map(childNode => (
        <TreeNode 
          {...props}
          node={childNode}          
          level={level + 1}
        />
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

TreeNode.defaultProps = {
  level: 0,
};
```

in this, inside the `StyledTreeNode` CSS if I put `position: relative` I am unable to click on the arrows and make the children files collapse back once they are opened like they are supposed to.

However, if I remove the `position`, it becomes

[image: Without relative position]

You can see the child nodes have come down in position, but now I can click on the arrows again and the children file collapses back.

How can I fix this so the children's files collapse on clicking the arrow and children don't come down in position respective to their parent's node?

Comment: You aren't trying to implement a tree view, though, so that article won't help and has sent you down the wrong path. Here are two packages you can use to learn from: [react-finder](https://github.com/Frezc/react-finder) [react-mac-finder](https://github.com/ruoru/react-mac-finder#readme).

Comment: You need to focus on the proper use of Flexbox layout with your CSS. You can [start with this info](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and then you'll understand what [this layout](https://www.flexboxpatterns.com/card-group) would do to help you approach your problem from the correct angle.

Comment: Thanks @Adam the repo helped a lot!